# Countdown plugin taking div id in Chrome not in Firefox, IE

Tags: jquery, datetime, firefox, jquery-countdown

I am making a project in which a date is passed by a form which then attaches a new div to the page with a unique id and timer via a function. While this project works perfectly in Chrome, it does not in Firefox, IE. The problem is with the id. I get the id alert in countdown() function but not inside countdown plugin as specified in code.
Interestingly, if there's only one div with id like "id" rather than multiple divs with unique ids like "id1","id2","id3" the plugin works in Firefox as well. So the problem is Firefox is somehow not parsing the multiple ids inside countdown plugin. Please see countdown(id) function.

```
    function add_countdown_handler() {
    $('.countdownParentDiv').each(function () {
        var btn = this;
        countdown(btn.id);
    });
}

function countdown(id) {

var date = $('#end_date'+id).val();  //eg- 2016-01-01 00:00:00
alert(id);  **//working**
alert(date);  **//working**

    $('#countdown'+id).countdown({ date: date}, function() {
        alert('id:'+id);  **//not working**
        alert('date:'+d);  **//not working**

    });
}
```

//This the countdown plugin which works fine

```
(function($) {
$.fn.countdown = function (options,callback) {

    var settings = {'date': null};

    if(options) {
        $.extend(settings, options);
    }
    var this_sel = $(this);

    function count_exec() {
        eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000;

        currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);

        if(eventDate <= currentDate) {
            callback.call(this);
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        seconds = eventDate-currentDate;
        days = Math.floor(seconds/(60*60*24));
        seconds -= days*60*60*24;
        hours = Math.floor(seconds/(60*60));
        seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
        minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60);
        seconds -= minutes * 60;

        days = (String(days).length !==2) ? '0' + days : days;
        hours = (String(hours).length !==2) ? '0' + hours : hours;
        minutes = (String(minutes).length !==2) ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = (String(seconds).length !==2) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

        if(!isNaN(eventDate)) {
            this_sel.find('.days').text(days);
            this_sel.find('.hours').text(hours);
            this_sel.find('.mins').text(minutes);
            this_sel.find('.secs').text(seconds);
        }
    }
    count_exec();
    var interval = setInterval(count_exec, 1000);
}
```

})(jQuery);

This is what I get in **Chrome** which is perfect. **Here timer is working**:
[image: Image from Chrome- Timer is working]

This is the same photo but clipped from **Firefox** (**Here the timer is 00:00:00...**)

[image: Image from Firefox- Timer is not working]

Comment: The problem is not in Firefox, the problem is in your code, but we can't know that because the explanation you've given us is vague. If the plugin works fine with firefox, something wrong you are making, so Firefox is not guilty.

Comment: What is the plugin that you are using? I've found that: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html but the initialise is different than yours

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude I learnt this plugin from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z290okjnAnM&list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810&index=133

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude But Sir if the timer is working fine in Chrome (with multiple timers) and even in Firefox (if there's only one div), how can the coding be wrong? Moreover, I'm getting the id alert in the countdown function, however, just not when I attach .countdown() plugin with the respective id inside countdown function.